# Как с помощью fcm отправлять высокоприоритетные пуши?

Tags: android, fcm

Я использую fcm для отправки push уведомлений, отправляю я их как data. Но нигде не помечаю приоритет сообщения. Для взаимодействия с fcm использую retrofit. Но я не знаю, в какой блок вставлять Android priority high(в header или в body, или нужно создавать отдельный блок).
Класс Message:

```
public class Message {
public Data data;
public Android android;
public String to;

public Message(Data data, Android android, String to) {
    this.android = android;
    this.data = data;
    this.to = to;
}
```

}

Класс с приоритетом по докам.

```
public class Android{
public String priority;

public Android(String priority){
    this.priority = priority;
}}
```

Интерфейс для обработки запроса

```
public interface APIService {
@Headers(
        {
                "Content-Type:application/json",
                "Authorization:key=...."})
@POST("fcm/send")
Call<MyResponse> sendNotification(@Body Message body);}
```

После этих изменений, всё равно получаю priority: normal

Comment: Судя по [доке](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidMessagePriority) должно быть примерно так: `{
  "message":{"android":{
      "priority":"high"
    }}`

Comment: Да, я читал... Но предположил что можно в уже существующий блок закинуть. Понял спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы имеете в виду. Приведенный мной пример не должен работать, т.к. неполон. Вы можете в уже имеющийся json добавить нужный объект или поле, если объект уже есть

Comment: Ну, я имел ввиду что можно ли в самом body сразу указать. Но вы уже ответили в принципе. Просто отдельным постоянным свойством задам его при формировании message и всё. Ещё раз благодарю.)

Comment: Добавил свойства с приоритетом, но всё равно когда пуш приходит, помечается как normal... В вопросе описал классы.

Comment: Судя по [доке](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message), гугл может решить за вас должен ли ваш пуш быть приоритетным и изменить его: `High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized.`